# Using non W3C valid attributes on HTML elements

Tags: jquery, html

What is your opinion about using non valid attributes on html elements for easier jQuery selectors etc ?

Eg.

```
<div name="myDiv"></div>
```

According to Visual Studio the name attribute is not valid for a div element.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462237/problem-with-non-standard-html-attributes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using "dummy" classes (and the jQuery class selector) to disambiguate naming of html elements.  100% compliant approach.

[Class Selector (“.class”)](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Comment: The problem for me when using the class is that it's a conflict with my css. I want to have the same css for a bunch of elements but want to query only a handful of them at a time so I need another discriminator attribute.

Comment: The class attribute takes a space separated list of classes. Give the elements multiple classes. `class="transport bus"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely *must*, use the `data` pseudo-namespace; such as `data-id` or `data-name`.

**Edit:** Using the `data` pseudo-namespace is far better than perverting the usage of an existing attribute like `class` or `id`.

Comment: This is a fine approach for adding metadata, but you would need something like John Resig's jQuery Metadata plugin to make it compelling for use with jQuery.

Answer (score -3):

If you still wanted to remain w3c compliant, the w3c allows `title` attribute for extra information, which you can use in lieu of adding new non-standard attributes.

Comment: The title attribute is for advisory information about an element, it is **presented** to users. It is a **very** poor choice of attribute to use to store arbitrary data that you want to access via JavaScript.